# Can't find my .minecraft folder in Windows 10

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, windows-10

I currently use Windows 10 and I'm running Minecraft 1.8.

I have seen people say run `%appdata&\.minecraft\` but that never worked for me. I really want to download a mod, but I can't until I find this folder.

Answer (score 5):

Unless you only made this typo when typing the question, the problem is that you have a typo in the folder path. Make sure that the symbols are entered correctly.

Correct path: `%APPDATA%\.minecraft`

Common typos:

- `%APPDATA&\.minecraft`
- `%APPDATA%.minecraft`

[image]

Comment: You can also type it into the search bar on the taskbar.

Comment: @angussidney Doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: I usually just use %appdata% and then click on the .minecraft folder. That works for me. And I'm talking about the search bar next to start, not in windows explorer

Comment: @angussidney %appdata% then clicking .minecraft does  work, although it looks as if it's searching for the folder of name %appdata% rather than just going to the path, so can be a bit slow.

Comment: Let's add, if you do this frequently, it may be a good idea just to create a shortcut to the folder on your desktop.

Answer (score 2):

On the Minecraft Start Screen, you can go into `Options > Resource Packs...` and click `Open Resource Pack Folder`. It will take you to `.../.minecraft/resourcepacks`. Then navigate to the parent directory which should hopefully take you to your `.minecraft` folder.

Answer (score 0):

go to your windows bar and search `Run` then type `%appdata%` after that enter and you'll see `.minecraft` click and go to mods place your mod in close/minimize it open MC and load up the forge version of what version your mod is for e.g floocraft 1.7.10 load up forge 1.7.10

Answer (score 0):

If you still cannot find the folder after trying the command in Run, try  **re-installing** Minecraft, and then check your folder again.

Comment: That really shouldn't be necessary, unless the folder is missing to begin with. But as the OP says he's able to run the game, it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

- As an alternative, search Windows (using Windows Search, Cortana, or a program like [Everything](https://www.voidtools.com/), which is a lot faster) for the file `realms_persistence.json` (or [other files that are unique to Minecraft](https://minecraft.wiki/w/.minecraft)).
  This file, as part of Minecraft, can be found in the folder you're looking for, even if for some reason the `.minecraft` folder's name got changed, or if it's no longer in `C:\Users\*user*\AppData\(Roaming\)`.

---

- According to [this website](https://help.mojang.com/customer/portal/articles/1480874-where-are-minecraft-files-stored-), the Minecraft folder can be found in
  `C:\Users\(your pc username)\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.MinecraftUWP_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState\games\com.mojang\` (the string of random characters could vary, I assume).

Answer (score -1):

You can only find the folder if you have bought the java edition which is on the official website.

if you have downloaded windows edition this is not possible

Comment: Do you have a source for this?

Comment: That's nonsense, except, maybe, the folder has a different name, but all data on your pc is findable.